# WSO2 IS 5.10 Set custom message while using expired reset password link

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 IS 5.10 version. When I click on forgot password multiple times, previous links gets expired and only the latest link will redirect to enter email page.
If we click on a previous reset password link which is expired, then it gets redirected to black page.
I have to provide custom content in the page like " Link is expired".
How can we do that.

Comment: You can customize `accountrecoveryendpoint` JSP page for that

Comment: Do you get the blank pages once you click on the expired password rest links received via emails? Don't the latest password reset link received, redirect you to set the new password? What did you mean by `only latest link will redirect to enter email page`?

Comment: Yes with latest reset email it is redirecting to reset password page and able to reset successfully. We only want that in case any user by mistakenly or accidentally click on expired link it should show proper messages that your link is expired. Now with blank page users are getting confused. My requirement is in which page we can write custom message and how can we check the link is expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the password reset link is clicked the user will be redirected to `https://<host>:<port>/accountrecoveryendpoint/confirmrecovery.do?<query-params>` That is https://github.com/wso2/identity-apps/blob/master/apps/recovery-portal/src/main/webapp/password-recovery-confirm.jsp

There is a logic to validate the confirmation code and check whether the link is expired or not.
https://github.com/wso2/identity-apps/blob/bddc96bf2d805f86446847a8f30429c882581cfa/apps/recovery-portal/src/main/webapp/password-recovery-confirm.jsp#L61

NOTE: Refer to relevant tag for 5.10.0

In IS-5.10.0, once you click on expired password reset links received to your emails the following error message will be shown, not a blank page.

[image]

If you apply this fix https://github.com/wso2/identity-apps/pull/1663/files you can display a proper error message as `Invalid password reset link.`